# editing PDF with PDFKit

Tags: objective-c, pdf, pdfkit

i'm writing an application in objective-c (using cocoa). i have a PDF template, i need to substitute actual values into placeholders in PDF and then save the result into new PDF.

how can i edit PDF with PDF Kit? can't find anything about editing in documentation, it's all about parsing...

or maybe anyone will recommend other library to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PDFKit may be the way to go, but the possibility of edition are very restrictive. It does not provide text replacement function. You can try to use PDF annotations, as there are many manipulation methods for that (but maybe it is not enough for your needs).

Comment: excuse me, I have a problem too and I need more explanation. I am new to pdfkit and I want to implement an editor for user which they can type and insert images on it and then converts it to pdf. does pdfkit have any special ability to do this? if not so what exactly shall I do? Appreciate if help me even in a word.